# Center vertically and horizontally a rotated div

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, center

I'm trying to center horizontally and vertically a DIV inside the window. Easy with a little bit of CSS and JS. But the problem is that my DIV is rotated (-33deg).

So I don't find how to center it properly. I tried to play with transform-origin, and with a calculation in jQuery, but didn't succeed.

$('mydiv').width() give me the width of the DIV not-rotated...not the actual "diagonal" width... (Same for the height).

I can't fix it manually with a fixed margin, because the website needs to be responsive...

Is it possible ?

This is the result that I need to have :

http://hpics.li/497b120

Thank you very much for your help !

Morgan

(Sorry if I did some english mistakes :s)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of css transforms, absolute positioning, and transform origin seems to have done it for me.

```
.element {
  transform: rotateZ(30deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Little demo: http://jsbin.com/suxawefabe/1/

Comment: Thank you, I will try this this evening. I'll tell you if it's ok !

Comment: @Morgan If this was the solution to your problem, you should consider accepting the answer